# deal with boolean api in js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

One of my api response with boolean(with the name: `used`), my logic is if the response is used will show `red_light` and `green_light` if not used.

```
const red_light = <div className="h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full bg-red-700 mr-2"></div>
const green_light = <div className="h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full bg-green-400 mr-2"></div>

function lighting(code) {
    fetch(`API`)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(
                    `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}`
                );
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((actualData) => {
            return (actualData.used ? red_light : green_light)
        })}

const MembershipLight = (code) => {
    return (
        lighting(code)
    );
};

export default MembershipLight;
```

but the page gone blank, which part i am doing wrong?

i try to `console.log` with the `actualData`, it shows the whole part of the response including `used` with `true`/`false`, but when i `console.log("actualData.used")`, it shows `undefined` in the console.

`actureData` (from postman)

```
[
    {
        "used": true,
        "create_date": "1644490502",
        "update_date": "1666694655"
    }
]
```

Comment: can you add `actualData` too ?

Comment: It should be `actualData[0].used ? red_light : green_light`

Comment: i think it's not work

Comment: It won't as you are not returning anything from function as below answer ...

Answer (score 2):

You should probably change approach and declare a `used` state to store the returned boolean value and use conditional rendering to adjust the class accordingly.
Also, as suggested by @KcH, if your response is an array, you should access the element with an index:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MembershipLight = (code) => {
  const [used, setUsed] = useState(false);

  const lighting = () => {
    fetch(`API`)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(
          `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}`
        );
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((actualData) => {
      if (actualData.length > 0) {
        setUsed(actualData[0].used)
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    lighting();
  }, []);

  return <div className={`h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full mr-2 ${used ? 'bg-red-700' : 'bg-green-400'}`}></div>;
};

export default MembershipLight;
```

Comment: I just copy your code, i think its work.
but i still wonder why when i console.log(actualData.used) it will show undefined

Comment: Because `actualData` is an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, you're not returning anything from your `lighting` function. You should return the result of the `fetch`. Currently, your `MembershipLight` returns `undefined` due to that.

Comment: i try to put `let light = ""` just below the function, and `light =  (actualData.used ? red_light : green_light)` under `.then`, the page is not blank now. but the lighting function are still not work

Comment: `actualData[0].used`.